# Solving modulus equation systems

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences, chinese-remainder-theorem

I am studying for a test in discrete math and I created my own question but I cannot seem to solve it.

Is it possible to solve the following equation system (without brainless testing), and if so, how?

$$x \equiv 5 \pmod 3\\
x \equiv 2 \pmod 7$$

My attempt: 
$$x=3a + 5 $$

$$x=7b + 2$$

$$3\mid(x-5)$$
$$7\mid(x-2)$$

I cannot seem to continue beyond this point. Can I solve it with least common multiple or something?

Comment: I guess you should also take a look at this thread [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/why-should-we-accept-answers) on why accepting answers is important. And [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a real quick tutorial on MathJax.

Answer (score 4):

In general, the solution to

$$x=a_1 \text{ mod } m_1$$
$$x=a_2 \text{ mod } m_2$$

is

$$x=\left[a_1M_1M_1' +a_2M_2M_2'\right] \ \ \text{ mod } m_1m_2$$

where $M_i = \dfrac{m_1m_2}{m_i}$ and $M_i' = M_i^{-1}$ modulo $m_i$.

So $$x=(5\cdot 7\cdot 1 + 2\cdot 3\cdot 5) \ \ \text{ mod } 21 = 2$$

This process is explained in the standard constructive proof of the Chinese Remainder Theorem (see [here](http://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/numbertheory/crt.html)), and is easily generalized to three or more equations to $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_iM_iM_i' \text{ mod } \prod m_i$

Comment: Damnm that was hard to understand haha. But I think I somewhat get it now, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Actually, this is a rather simple problem.  $5\equiv2\pmod3$, so you have $x$ is $2$ more than a multiple of $3$ and $2$ more than a multiple of $7$.  Combine these conditions, and $x$ must be $2$ more than a multiple of $21$, or $x\equiv2\pmod{21}$.

We can make a tougher problem by reversing the first condition to $x\equiv3\pmod5$.  In which case you have

$$x=7b+2\equiv3\pmod5$$
$$2b\equiv1\equiv6\pmod5$$
$$b\equiv3\pmod5$$

Combining this with $x=7b+2$ yields

$$x=7(5k+3)+2=35k+21+2=35k+23$$
$$x\equiv23\pmod{35}$$

Comment: may be it is not that simple for the op.

Comment: @abel They're easy when equivalent to the same value, as they are both equivalent to 2 in this case.  I've added more to illustrate how one might tackle a slightly harder problem.

Comment: the answer looks much nicer now. sorry about the previous comment. what i was try to say was that simple is a relative term.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was really helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

we can write $$x=5+3k_1$$ and $$x=2+7k_2$$ where $k_1,k_2$ are integer numbers, thus you have to solve the Diophntine equation $$3=-3k_1+7k_2$$

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), first we notice that $\gcd (3,7) = 1$.

We may tackle this by looking at sections, $\mod 3$ section, $\mod 7$ section. Now, you first choose a section and put an quivalent to zero on the other sections so they will disappear for example $3 \equiv  0\mod 3$ so we write

$$x = \underbrace{\ }_{\mod 3} + \underbrace{3}_{\mod 7} $$

Next we will have

$$x = \underbrace{7 }_{\mod 3} + \underbrace{3}_{\mod 7}$$

Notice that $7 \equiv 1 \mod 3$ then if you multiply by $5$ you get $35 \equiv 5 \mod 3$. If you hit $x \mod 3$ we get

$$x = 5 \mod 3$$

Using the same idea we have that $3\dot \ 5 \equiv 1\mod 7$ then $2 \dot\ 3\dot \ 5 \equiv2 \mod 7$

and then

$$x = 35 + 30  = 65$$

simply put we have that once applying the Chinese Remainder Theorem

$$x \equiv 65 \equiv 2\mod 3\dot \ 7$$

which gives $$x \equiv 2 \mod 21$$